What's the difference between abstract open-book decomposition and non-abstract one?
I am reading "Lectures on Open Book Decompositions and Contact Structures" by Etnyre.
I'm also interested in Giroux's correspondence, so the "up to isotopy" things are really matter.
In this note, the abstract open-book decomposition is much weaker notion that non-abstract one because it could distinguishes the associated $3$-fold $M_\phi$ and the bindings and pages, $(B_\phi, \pi_\phi)$ only up to diffeomorphism, while the non-abstract one distinguish them up to isotopy.
So, here are the questions:

What does it mean exactly, that the open-book decomposition determines the binding and the pages up to isotopy in $M$?

Why the abstract open-book decomposition discuss them up to only diffeomorphism? If $M_\phi$ is fixed, then we can discuss the binding and the pages up to isotopy in $M$?


I'm not quite sure exactly what is the difference between them.
I've read it again, but still, I'm not sure what's the problem. What I'm currently feeling about this problem is that we're just discussing about the same thing just in the different layer.
